# Google geocoding - how to get reference or id from lat,lng using REST api

Tags: node.js, api, google-maps, rest, google-maps-api-3

I've been pulling my head on this one for days...
I'm using Node.js to make http calls to Google maps REST API's
I need to go over records of locations in my database, and using the lat,lng - find the google location id or reference in a given resolution - say "country" or "administrative_level_1" for example...

I found these two rest calls to be the closest to what I need:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
latlng=47.333333,13.333333
&sensor=false
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
&result_type=administrative_area_level_1
```

this call takes in lat,lng and the desired resolution and give back an accurate result, but with no id or reference...
This is the result json:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Salzburg",
               "short_name" : "Sbg.",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Austria",
               "short_name" : "AT",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Salzburg, Austria",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.04121,
                  "lng" : 13.9965099
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 46.94347,
                  "lng" : 12.07669
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.80949,
               "lng" : 13.05501
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.04121,
                  "lng" : 13.9965099
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 46.94347,
                  "lng" : 12.07669
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

the only other alternative I have so far is to use the autocomplete REST API like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?
key=YOUR_API_KEY
&location=47.333333,13.333333
&sensor=false
&language=en
&types=(regions)
&input=Austria
```

The problem with this one is that since it is meant for autocomplete purposes, it is required to pass in the 'input' parameter and not just lat,lng which is better for me. It is better because the locations I am trying to process are in many languages and it would be a nightmare to specify for each record its languages.

This is the result json for the previous call:
I need to iterate on the predictions objects and found the ones in the resolution I'm looking for...

```
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Austria",
         "id" : "e16f8e9f2a60f60a0881c41488ff3869e4f938a4",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 7,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "reference" : "CiQfAAAAF11VDI_p7OWWL8woW8cOfCDDeA0iE-NMQwQsbQhouSASECau8aTrkIVsiUcGrmnNHhwaFEmcUvCjjjsHRDznswqC_xeOYiBR",
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Austria"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "country", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Lower Austria, Austria",
         "id" : "03ea5cab0b5abe4cb16f66e9a42c27d040ce2b3c",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 7,
               "offset" : 6
            }
         ],
         "reference" : "CjQuAAAAznpNXppnhg3bl-36bfMr4tsQa3ZjJJWmtUuHIEzEy4RL9M_LeSGc8muP-_h_e89gEhCFjfuwyex9OA36skw8bD45GhQ14NncFQk-AHOILKC4IqEPe-XqDw",
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Lower Austria"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 15,
               "value" : "Austria"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Vienna, Austria",
         "id" : "f622c175d668fbf75e7488ddf7b1a04ecb667788",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "reference" : "CjQnAAAAD88YSerev6ZNhRw6hI0P9g_Brsjzc_qN5PqKtugj7GXIMbhqKK1qvJXYprMFu67mEhDYSzeYQwEQFjnOxjb3SsxAGhTocUQpKtR1CoM7sYJJROGImDMQzQ",
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Vienna"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 8,
               "value" : "Austria"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Oberosterreich, Austria",
         "id" : "5ecb86bf53005b6cd7499f660e2312089a955ced",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 14,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "reference" : "CjQvAAAAgtYVlhBFCDPBgcJu_7CXHJ8ncd3m6IozPSg3YzaLL4kXVtQowpjx4kc2K-Tqm_0YEhCn4rEiM0MaChwBhkki0qu_GhRgpGKjjh4Hq4aN2n9jFjdfc-Xl8Q",
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Oberosterreich"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 16,
               "value" : "Austria"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Austrian District, Gyumri, Shirak, Armenia",
         "id" : "3948451df8a40142c1adeeeb4a969dc1c7d82d39",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 7,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "reference" : "ClRCAAAANrMT8rQH819b7rtJiCbaq0XbDip8VuQCO7EvoIkVmg4xUyQtxGiFhm9sF52hTbtp8PjR-b0_dCLn-ZXceYfJJ64j1hwxbuthSHomBoGBphMSEPC8ZwPtn6dOrYb_duar-tcaFIFbhTX9HWS4UDzF2exZcw2YUh9o",
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Austrian District"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 19,
               "value" : "Gyumri"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 27,
               "value" : "Shirak"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 35,
               "value" : "Armenia"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "sublocality", "political", "geocode" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The original data is derived from the geonames database we used. We are switching to use google maps API's in all sections of our applications hence I need to convert those to google location id's using the lat,lng and resolution only... names are out of my control since they are a given. and in many languages...

I'd appreciate it if you can point out a REST API call that is able to do that or a sequence of http calls for that matter...

Appreciate it.
Ajar

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [API picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker) from the Google web site, I would suggest the following API:

Convert the latitude/longitude coordinates of a geographic location to an address (reverse geocoding).
[Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) (a web service)